# Transform filename "Name - XXxYY".mkv(or avi,mp4) with "Name - SXXEYY".mkv(or avi,mp4)

Tags: python, replace

I have this part of python code that checks if a file is a movie or a show

```
if search('[Ss][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+', self.name) is not None:
    series = self.name + 'FIN'
    series = sub(' - [Ss][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+.*?FIN', '', series)
    series = sub('[Ss][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+.*?FIN', '', series)
    series = sub('FIN', '', series)
    series = transSERIES(series)
    url = 'http://www.thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=' + series + self.language
    self.getTVDbData(url, '0')
```

Unfortunately all my shows in the library are formatted like this and of course are not recognized as series:

```
"ShowName - XXxYY.mkv" XXxYY for XX(Saison)xYY(Episode)
```

How could I transform (without renaming all the files) `"ShowName - XXxYY"` to `"ShowName - SXXEYY"` before the if condition ?

```
if search('[Ss][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+', self.name) is not None:
```

Comment: Please give us an actual filename and what you'd like it to be transformed into.

Comment: For example "City on a Hill - 01x02.mkv" is ignored had to be ""City on a Hill - S01E02.mkv" to be processed.Not a problem renaming few files but with big library it's a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can first extract the "XXxYY" using the `split` method of a string:

```py
with_extention = show_name.split(" ")[-1] # result : 03x13.mkv
without_extention = XXxYY.split(".")[0] # result : 03x13
season, episode = without_extention.split("x")[0], XXxYY.split("x")[1]
```

Finally you can rearange it by adding the retrieved informations the the initial file name using concatenation.

```py
base_name = show_name[0: len(show_name)-len(with_extension)]
finale_name = base_name + "S" + season + "E" + episode
```